# SQL Select Most Common Column based on Group

Tags: sql, join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using Snowflake to query data and one of the tables has some issues that are out of my control.

There are several item id's that have the same item description for most records except for one. For example:

| Item ID | Item Description |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | Coca Cola Original |
| 1234 | Coca Cola Original |
| 1234 | Coke Orgnl |
| 1234 | Coca Cola Original |

I am trying to join this table to bring in the Item Description but the result is two records due to the different naming conventions. How can I create a query to select the most common item description for each unique Item ID?

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake has a window operation, [MODE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/mode), which you could make use off. It should ideally return the most common value inside the column.

```
WITH DATA AS (
  SELECT 1234 AS ITEM_ID, 'Coca Cola Original' AS ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1234 AS ITEM_ID, 'Coca Cola Original' AS ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1234 AS ITEM_ID, 'Coca Cola Original' AS ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1234 AS ITEM_ID, 'Coke Orgnl' AS ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1234 AS ITEM_ID, 'Coca Cola Original' AS ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 12345 AS ITEM_ID, 'Fake Coke' AS ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 12345 AS ITEM_ID, 'Coke' AS ITEM_DESCRIPTION
)
SELECT ITEM_ID, MODE(ITEM_DESCRIPTION)  FROM DATA
GROUP BY ITEM_ID;
```

[image]

The caveat is that Snowflake does not know which is the correct one, and possibly choose at random if the number of occurrences match.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH DATA AS (
  SELECT 1234 AS ITEM_ID, 'Coca Cola Original' AS ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1234 AS ITEM_ID, 'Coca Cola Original' AS ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1234 AS ITEM_ID, 'Coca Cola Original' AS ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1234 AS ITEM_ID, 'Coke Orgnl' AS ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1234 AS ITEM_ID, 'Coca Cola Original' AS ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 12345 AS ITEM_ID, 'Fake Coke' AS ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 12345 AS ITEM_ID, 'Coke' AS ITEM_DESCRIPTION
), cte2 as (
select 
    item_id, item_description, count(1)  as cnt 
from data 
    group by 1,2 
)
select 
    item_id, item_description
from cte2
    qualify row_number() over(partition by item_id order by cnt desc) = 1
```

By using the in the order by clause if there is a tie i.e. the count is same then add another sort order based on the item_description asc or desc